# How to install SSL certificate using FTP or WP dashboard

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ftp

Is it possible to install a **ssl** certificate on a wordpress site, just using **FTP or WordPress dashboard** ? Because I have no access SSH or cPanel.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, because the cert should be installed in domain name then in web server.
So we should have access to the server and domaine name hosting also.
Thank you All.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a SSL certificate you can edit the webserver configuration file and add the path to the SSL certificate and then install the wordpress plugin as @Farhan Ali just said.

Comment: Thanks @Marco ,yes we purchased the certs, but where can we find the webserver file of configuration ? we have just WP and FTP Access!

Comment: Which server do you use? Do you have an VPS Server or something?

Comment: Ask your shared web hosting provider if he could do that. Which provider do you use?

Comment: We are in UniMedia.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link it may help, it's WP plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/#installation

Comment: Thanks @Farhan Ali, but this plugin needs that the certificate should be installed on server before install it on WP Dashboard